# Trouble trying to dynamically add methods to Python class (i.e. django-tables2 'Table')

Tags: python, django, metaprogramming, django-tables2

So for a Django project, I would really like to be able to generate and display tables (**not** based on querysets) dynamically without needing to know the contents or schema beforehand.

It looks like the [django-tables2](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest) app provides nice functionality for rendering tables, but it requires that you either explicitly declare column names by declaring attributes on a custom-defined Table subclass or else provide a model for it infer the columns.

I.e, to use a column named "name", you'd do:

```
class NameTable(tables.Table):
   name = tables.Column()
```

The Tables class does not provide a method for adding columns post-facto because, from reading the source, it seems to use a metaclass that sweeps the class attributes on __new__ and locks them in.

It seemed like very simple metaprogramming would be an elegant solution. I defined a basic class factory that accepts column names are arguments:

```
def define_table(columns):
    class klass(tables.Table): pass              
    for col in columns:
        setattr(klass, col, tables.Column())
    return klass
```

Sadly this does not work. If I run `

```
x = define_table(["foo", "bar"])(data)
x.foo
x.bar
```

I get back:

```
<django_tables2.columns.base.Column object at 0x7f34755af5d0>
<django_tables2.columns.base.Column object at 0x7f347577f750>
```

But if I list the columns:

```
print x.base_columns
```

I get back nothing i.e. {}

I realize that there are probably simpler solutions (e.g. just bite the bullet and define every possible data configuration in code, or don't use django-tables2 and roll my own), but I am now treating this as an opportunity to learn more about meta programming, so I would really like to make this work this way.

Any idea what I'm wrong doing wrong? My theory is that the __new__ method (which is redefined in the metaclass Table uses) is getting invoked when klass is defined rather than when it's instantiated, so by the time I tack on the attributes it's too late. But that violates my understanding of when __new__ should happen. Otherwise, I'm struggling to understand how the metaclass __new__ can tell the difference between defined-in-code attributes vs. dynamically defined ones.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're on the right track here, but instead of creating a barebones class and adding attributes to it, you should use the [type()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type) built-in function. The reason it's not working the way you're trying, is because the metaclass has already done its work.

Using `type()` allows you to construct a new class with your own attributes, while setting the base class. Meaning - you get to describe the fields you want as a blueprint to your class, allowing the `Table`s metaclass to take over after your definition.

[Here's an example](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DynamicModels) of using `type()` with django. I've used this myself for my own project (with some slight variations) but it should give you a nice place to start from, considering you're already almost there.

```
def define_table(columns):
    attrs = dict((c, tables.Column()) for c in columns)
    klass = type('DynamicTable', (tables.Table,), attrs)
    return klass
```

Comment: Awesome. This works! Alternatively, it seems that just doing `table.base_columns[col] = col` works, but that may be breaking something I'm not seeing since it circumvents the column creation code. So your solution is much better. Future readers should also check out @BrenBarn's answer since it explains why my method was failing.

Comment: @rogueleaderr glad it worked for you. While it's in your mind, you should have a read about metaclasses, and the various functions they provide. They're especially useful to understand when playing around with Django, as Models and Forms both use them, and sometime you're going to have to get into the nitty-gritty.

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing the `__new__` of a "regular" class with the `__new__` of a metaclass.  As you note, `Table` relies on `__new__` method on its *metaclass*.  The metaclass is indeed invoked when the class is defined.  The class is itself an instance of the metaclass, so defining the class is instantiating the metaclass.  (In this case, `Table` is an instance of `DeclarativeColumnMetaClass`.)  So by the time the class is define, it's too late.

One possible solution is to write a `Table` subclass that has some method `refreshColumns` or the like.  You could adapt the code from `DeclarativeColumnMetaclass.__new__` to essentially make `refreshColumns` do the same magic again.  Then you could call `refreshColumns()` on your new class.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I think Josh's answer is a bit more elegant, but your answer helps explain why my method failed.