# Django-tables2 - dynamically adding columns to table - not adding attrs to table tag in html

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

In my Django project I need to have tables which columns are dynamic and depend on what is in the database. So I found a solution in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134488/trouble-trying-to-dynamically-add-methods-to-python-class-i-e-django-tables2/14134574#14134574) and it works but with a little problem. Here's the class with a table I'm extending dynamically:

```
class ClientsTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        attrs = {"class": "paleblue", "orderable":"True", "width":"100%"}
        fields = ('name',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ClientsTable, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.counter = itertools.count()

    def render_row_number(self):
        return '%d' % next(self.counter)

    def render_id(self, value):
        return '%s' % value
```

And here is the method that extends the class:

```
def define_table(roles):
    attrs = dict((r.name, tables.Column() for r in roles)
    klass = type('DynamicTable', (ClientsTable,), attrs)
    return klass
```

When I'm creating a table in views.py like this:

```
table = define_table(roles)(queryset)
```

The table shows columns like I wanted, but in the html code I see that it ignored the attrs:

```
{"class": "paleblue", "orderable":"True", "width":"100%"}
```

So there is no css style for paleblue, which is important to me. 
I feel that it might be something with Meta class but fields and model are working, so I have no idea why attrs are not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, [meta options are not inherited](https://github.com/bradleyayers/django-tables2/issues/85) in django-tables2. So you may check the workarounds discussed in the issue to see if something fits or you can manuall add a Meta class to your dynamic table. To do that, you can your define_table method like this:

```
def define_table(roles):
  attrs = dict((r.name, tables.Column() for r in roles)
  attrs['Meta'] = type('Meta', (), dict(attrs={"class":"paleblue", "orderable":"True", "width":"100%"}) )
  return klass
```

Oops after more than two years I noticed that there was an error in my code -- I'd forgotten to include the line `klass = type('DynamicTable', (ClientsTable,), attrs)` before `return klass` above. I'm, adding it now for  completeness.

Comment: Nice stuff! Not exactly addressing my issue, but I could modify your snippet to solve my problem and learned a lot about Python `type` and meta class action. Thx a bunch!

Comment: Glad I helped! I've also written various posts doing stuff with type at my blog: http://spapas.github.io/category/django.html

Answer (score 11):

For anyone looking for this now, from django-tables2 1.10 you add columns dynamically to a table by passing `extra_columns` to the `Table` constructor.

`extra_columns` should be a list of tuples, defining a column name and a `Column` object, eg.

```
class MyTable(Table):
    static_column = Column()

mytable = MyTable(extra_columns=[('dynamic_column', Column())]
```

See the API documentation at: http://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/api-reference.html#django_tables2.tables.Table